# Angular DatePicker is always including GMT when we don't want any value for GMT (not even UTC)

Tags: angular, typescript, date, datepicker

We have a typical Angular DatePicker component.

We're trying to return (via an HTTP POST) the date value of whatever the user has selected in the calendar.

[image]

What we would LOVE is this: `yyyy-MM-dd`. We don't want any GMT values at all, not even UTC. Just the date the person selected because that is related to the location of the product. Not their browser's local timezone or their computer/laptop's timezone. Imaging being in the USA and booking a doctor's appointment over in Hong Kong. They just want to book an appointment for 20th Dec, 2023 HongKong date/time but we don't know what that timezone is.

This is what my friend did:

```
const date == <the datepicker date>

const formattedDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-${(date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;

console.log(formattedDate);
```

which does work -> the value returned is `2023-12-20` (for example)!

But surely there's a better way to do this? Surely this is built into Angular already? or TypeScript?

I know there is the `.toLocaleString()` but that format's the value in a format we don't like: `dd/MM/2023, hh:mm:ss`

[image]

Our problem stems from that every time we look at the value of the calendar, the other person was doing this:

```
JSON.stringify(this.agreementEndDate)
```

which returned the value as UTC ... and just wanted the value as what they selected without any timezones.

[image]

So, is this the common way people are extracting the yyyy-MM-dd out of a datepicker to post back to a server?

Comment: The Date type in javascript is... painful, to say the least. That's why many (most?) front-end developers avoid it like fire. There's even a proposal for an official new API [here](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/). Until then, there are multiple different implementations of date objects. If you're working with material, take a look [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) for the most popular ones with built-in adapters. I know it's not a real answer, but it might push you in the right direction.